# ¿Como hago una validacion para cargar solo archivos PDF?

Tags: php, html

Necesito hacer un código de carga de archivos en PHP para que los usuarios de un sitio web puedan cargar solo PDFs, recogi este ejemplo de [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) como se muestra a continuacion:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}
?>
```

Quiero agregar que solo cargue archivos PDFs ¿Como podria hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

para restringir que solo acepte formato `pdf` solo nesesitas incluir un if

```php
<?php
try {
  $target_dir = "uploads/";
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
  $uploadOk = 1;
  $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

  if (!($imageFileType == 'pdf')) {
    throw new Exception('Este no es un archivo pdf');
  }

  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

    if($check !== false) {
      echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
      $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
      echo "File is not an image.";
      $uploadOk = 0;
    }
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

agregue una excepcion para manejar errores, tu ya tenias la variable `imageFileType` asi que solo faltaba la verificacion de eso.

Comment: It gives me this errors: Warning: Undefined array key "fileToUpload" in /storage/ssd3/570/21911570/public_html/index.php on line 16

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /storage/ssd3/570/21911570/public_html/index.php on line 16
Este no es un archivo pdf

Comment: @MartínBadino eso significa que esta funcionando la prevencion de errores

Answer (score 0):

No basta con que hagas "solo un código". Lo correcto es colocar varios "puntos de control". Por Ejemplo:

- En HTML restringes los archivos que no sean PDF en el atributo
  "***accept***" de la siguiente manera:

  ```
  <input type="file" id="foo" name="foo" accept=".pdf" style="height: 40px;">
  ```

  Así, el usuario solo podrá subir archivos con extensión PDF
- En con JavaScript validas el formulario que vas a enviar con el archivo así:

  ```
   let form  = document.getElementById('fooForm');
   let input = form.foo;
   let file  = input.files[0];

   if(file.type != 'application/pdf'){
       return false;
   }
  ```

De esta manera garantizas en el FrontEnd que sea solo formato PDF o no se envía
el formulario. Recuerda colocarle al formulario en la propiedad "***onSubmit***" que
pase por una función validadora.

- Y por último, en el BackEnd, con PHP, los input tipo "***file***" llegan a la super variable `$_FILES['foo']` la cual es un array que contiene la información del archivo subido por el usuario con 4 index importantes:

  ```
   $_FILES['foo']['name'];
   $_FILES['foo']['type'];
   $_FILES['foo']['size'];
   $_FILES['foo']['tmp_name'];
  ```

Para evitar que se suba un archivo que no sea de extensión PDF nos interesa el index "***type***" y puedes usar la siguiente validación:

```
    if(!strpos($foo, 'pdf')){
        // el error que desees retornar
        exit;
    }
```

***No sé si esto responda tu pregunta, pero espero que te sea de ayuda. Saludos!***

Answer (score -2):

Después de:

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

valida que sea PDF así:

```
if ($imageFileType == 'pdf') {
 // instrucciones
 } else {
 echo "Archivo NO válido; debe ser PDF.";
 }
```

Comment: En que se diferencia esta respuesta de la otra?

Comment: ¿cual otra? :-)

Comment: todas las otras.. que aporte esta?? mira por favor [answer]